# G++ OpenGL load multiple object

Tags: c++, file, opengl, .obj

I have a problem to load more than one file. Obj in OpenGL. I try to load the cmd file, but only the last file is load.

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
if(!load_object(argv[i], OBJECT_LIST))){
printf("Error with file %s", argv[i]);
}}
```

OBJECT_LIST- is GLuint

Where is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `OBJECT_LIST` is being overwritten each time the loop iterates.  I would imagine making use of an array is what you want:

```
GLuint OBJECT_LIST[2];

for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    if(!load_object(argv[i], OBJECT_LIST[i]))){
        printf("Error with file %s", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Another note:  is there a reason you're starting at `argv[0]`? That contains your application's filename, not the first argument.

Comment: Stil not work. In code I have line 'glCallList(OBJECT_LIST);' and here is error but when I comment these line or replace with 'for(int i=0;i<2;i++) glCallList(OBJECT_LIST[i]);' window is empty.

Comment: when I start with 1 app is close